# Check for Free Space on Linux, email if critical

Tags: linux, debian, bash-scripting

I just finished dealing with a server which had run out of space, and would like to setup monitoring on it now, to prevent it going critical in the future.

What I would like is to get an email sent to the `root` account (which forwards to my work email) when free space is below `xx`%, with it being configurable.

I know I can use the `df -h` command to get the human-readable text layout, but I don't want a report every day. I want to only have a report sent to me if certain partitions/mount points are filling up, and have less than a certain percentage still free.

I am comfortable scripting, but I do not know how I would go about this. Below is a sample output of the command I manually run anyways:

```
# df -h
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                   74G  6.4G   64G  10% /
udev                                                     10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                   387M  320K  387M   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/615e2eca-0e01-4f3f-99d3-5a0560a78f9a   74G  6.4G   64G  10% /
tmpfs                                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                   773M     0  773M   0% /run/shm
/dev/md0                                                939M   51M  841M   6% /boot
/dev/md3                                                844G  535G  266G  67% /images
/dev/md2                                                2.7T  1.7T  955G  64% /var
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
#!/bin/sh

MOUNTPOINTS="/ /home"
THRESHOLD=90

for MOUNT in ${MOUNTPOINTS}; do

  CURRENT=$(df ${MOUNT} | grep / | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/%//g')

  if [ "${CURRENT}" -gt "${THRESHOLD}" ] ; then
    mail -s 'Disk Space Alert' root << EOF

Your ${MOUNT} partition remaining free space is critically low. Used: ${CURRENT}%
EOF

  fi

done
```

This is based off of code by [Malik Arjun](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-send-email-alert-when-your-disk-space-gets-low).

Comment: Or : `MOUNTPOINTS=$(df | tail -n +2 | sort -k 6 | uniq -f 2 | awk ‘{ print $6 }’)` if you want all mount points… (Showing off... :-)

Comment: I tweaked it slightly, basically outputting the message to `stdout`, and using Cron to run it (which only emails if there's output). Good find though